# Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 - Finding SAS & SSD Disks Info

Tags: linux, rhel, disk, ssd, storage

I have a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 system. I want to find SAS & SSD disks parts and which parts combine to form which mount points on system or database (Oracle 11gR2) level. For example:

> sda + sdb + sdc = /BACKUP

And I want to which storage model using on the server.

I found this command for checking SSD:

```
lsblk -d -o name,rota
```

If rota's result equals zero, it is SSD (I'm not sure if it is not true).

But how can I find SAS disks?

I'm a newbie on Linux system, I couldn't find the exact answers to the questions I was looking for.

Best Regards,

Comment: Your question is not very clear, and I think your terminology is non-standard.

Comment: Please explain in written English what do you mean by `sda + sdb + sdc = /BACKUP` and explain a bit how much data do you manage (gigabytes, terabytes, petabytes) and what will happen to you if you lose some of it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch 11TB and I explained under your answer.

Comment: And **what will happen to you if some gigabytes get lost** - by your mistake or by hardware failure? How valuable is that data? What is your backup strategy? **Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/605795/edit) to improve it a lot.** What kind of data do you manage (porn video, or military secrets, or payrolls)

Comment: What *filesystems* are you using? Give in your question the output of  `df -h` and `mount` ... Without concrete details and some context, your question stays unclear. I voted to close it. **Consider [editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/605795/edit) your question** to give *a lot more details* but **don't comment your own question**. Explain also what is your computer.

Comment: Are you a newbie sysadmin/database admin, or have you some experience on non Linux systems? If yes, mention them in your question! And please **show the commands you did run and their output** in your question

Comment: **Good luck.** Expect to have problems in the future, unless allowed to get training or buy external support - or several technical books, and getting time to read them.  As I understand it, your situation is a disaster waiting to happen, so at least *cover your ass*

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't understand why you angry. I just asked a question. I can't explain myself because I'm a newbie as I said. Have a good day sir.

Comment: I am not angry, but empathic. But my feeling is that you are in trouble. And we cannot guess your work context.... Losing 1Gbytes in 11Tbytes is different if the gigabyte is health related data (e.g. Covid related lung scanner digital images) or if it data in some distributed video game. Both financial and human impacts are *very* different. It is not the same if you work in a hospital, a missile maker, or in a game company. If someone dies because of your mistake, you will have trouble. If just US$100 is lost, you will have less trouble.

Answer (score 2):

**You could be interested by the following commands** (to be *carefully* run as root in a terminal emulator, and sometimes *cleverly* combined in a [script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) or command [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix))): [fdisk(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fdisk.8.html), [hwinfo](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Hwinfo), [blkid(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/blkid.8.html), [mount(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html), [ls(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html), [df(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/df.1.html), [du(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html), [cpio(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cpio.1.html), [afio](https://linux.die.net/man/1/afio), [dd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html), [scp(1),](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html) [tar(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html), [lspci(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lspci.8.html), [lsblk(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsblk.8.html), [fsck(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fsck.8.html), [dmesg(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html), [lscpu(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lscpu.1.html), [lsusb(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsusb.8.html), [lsmod(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsmod.8.html), [findmnt(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/findmnt.8.html), [e4crypt(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/e4crypt.8.html)

See also [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [mount(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html), [mount_namespaces(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html), [ext4(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html), [fstab(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html), etc...

See also `/sys/` and `/dev/` and `/proc/`  so [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), [sysfs(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysfs.5.html),[filesystems(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/filesystems.5.html) and [sd(4)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/sd.4.html)

### Look also into the various [Linux HOWTOs](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/HOWTO-INDEX/howtos.html)

### Take a few hours to read documentation *before* running commands.

Since a mistake in commands could erase your disks and data. **Be prepared to make mistakes and to lose some data** (so backup important data on a remote system, perhaps using [rsync(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html)). Look -using [less(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html) or [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), etc...- inside textual files under `/etc/`

Write on paper -with a pencil- the commands you want to run (e.g. *before* running them as root), and the day you did run them. Expect to make mistakes. Write on paper the commands you want to learn.

You may need to install additional packages, or to compile open source programs from their source code.

> sda + sdb + sdc = /BACKUP

### What does that mean?

Read [inode(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html). Are you referring to [multi-volume filesystems](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/btrfs-integrated_volume_management) or [RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) ?

**Define and document in writing** (at least by emails to colleagues/clients) **your [backup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup) strategy.** You could need extra resources (training, consultancy, books, backup services, time, money, hardware, software).

If you use [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/) (but consider also [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) and [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/)) **spend a few days to read documentation**, and dump your important database (perhaps periodically thru [crontab(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) into `*.sql` files, maybe compressed with [bzip2](https://sourceware.org/bzip2/) or `gzip` etc...)

Of course read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and follow a week of Linux sysadmin training. Consider buying some support or training from Linux or database consultants in your area, and **discuss preemptively with your manager or client the possibility of losing or [leaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_security) data**.

Consider using [git](https://git-scm.com/) for your scripts (perhaps with [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [Python](https://python.org/) or [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)) and [database schemas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema). Try to find help from colleagues or locally (or external consultants)

> I'm a newbie on Linux system

## Above all, you need time, books, training, mentoring ....

> I couldn't find the exact answers to the questions I was looking for.

They could require *years* of work. [Free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) is about freedom, not cost.

And please **communicate** with client or manager and colleagues. It looks you are given responsibilities above your current technical skillsets (which happen to all of us). Discuss with manager or client the possibility of giving a lot more details on forum like this one, and the probability of some future computer related disaster.

## Good luck

Comment: Hi Basile. Firsly, thank you for your answer. For example; Let's say we have 10 discs. 3 of them are sda, sdb and sdc. Let this be the mount point /BACKUP created by combining sda, sdb and sdc disks. Where can I find such information?

Comment: What will happen to you if some data is lost?

Comment: I still don't understand your `sda + sdb + sdc = /BACKUP` equation, so please *improve your question*

Comment: I get the axe if some data lost. :)

Comment: **Please improve your question** (give more context, and links to documentation you have read) and tell us a bit more about that data. Being French, I don't understand "I get the axe"

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command (in a terminal as root)

```
lsscsi -t
```

to show transport information.

Comment: Hi. What is this meaning? Thank you.